# Format HTTP date message in PHP

Tags: php

Background:

I am building a simple chat program for iOS/Android. On the backend is an equally simple PHP/MySQL server that handles the messages. In some cases messages need to be delayed and not sent immediately. To handle this function I an sending messages via HTTP to a server that schedules when messages will be released. The format that it follows is below:

```
http://www.company.com:8899/?Env=env&AppName=####&Token=string
&Message=string&ScheduleDate=2010-08-31%2022:10:34%20-0400
&ScheduleAction=action
```

The most relevant part of the URL for this question is ScheduleDate which specifies the time/date that the message will be sent

Question:

I am having trouble getting the current date/time, putting it in the required format (YYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) and then accounting for the required delay. What I want to do is:

(1) get the current date/time
(2) add 5 minutes
(3) put it back into that URL string

Here is the segment with which I am building the string. I used $roomCreateDate to try and get the current date just to see if I could build the string without accounting for the delay. $comand should build the string to match the format above.

```
$roomCreateDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$command =  'localhost:8899/'.
                '?Env='. environment($appversion) .
                '&AppName=EchoFriendly'.
                '&Token=' . $devicetoken .
                '&Message=' . urlencode($apsPayload) .
        '&ScheduleDate=' . urlencode($roomCreateDate) .
        '&ScheduleAction=add';
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: use time() and/or strtotime()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$roomCreateDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+5 minutes'));
```

Comment: How is strtotime adding the +5 minutes? I want to understand what's going on if possible instead of just copying code

Comment: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#example-696 it basically takes the current UNIX timestamp and adds whatever time period you want as in the exmaples, and then puts that new timestamp value as the timestamp input for the date() function.

Answer (score 0):

You are having troubles adding the 5 minutes?

You can use the following instead of:

```
$roomCreateDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Try:

```
$roomCreateDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+5 minutes'));
```